# C# Caesar Shift decryption stops showing shifts after a number of shifts and shifts get longer

Tags: c#, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am developing a Ceaser Cipher which decrypts the .TXT file attached. It's got to show all possible shifts and results in the decrytped text. But what I have got so far just shows about 8 shifts and each shift is getting longer with more text which is not meant to happen. Can someone help me identify the problem in the below code?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"FilePath");
        string file;
        int shift = 0;
        string decoded_text;

        char character = '0';

        char[] alphabet = new char[26]
        {
        'A','B','C','D',
        'E','F','G','H',
        'I','J','K','L',
        'M','N','O','P',
        'Q','R','S','T',
        'U','V','W','X',
        'Y', 'Z'
         };

        Console.WriteLine("The encrypted text is \n{0}", text); //Displays the encrypted text, shows that it gathered the text correctly from the fiile

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            decoded_text = "";
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                character = c;

                if (!alphabet.Contains(character))
                {
                    decoded_text += character;
                    continue;
                }

                shift = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, character) - i;
                if (shift <= 0) shift = shift + 26;

                if (shift >= 26) shift = shift - 26;

                text += alphabet[shift];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nShift {0} \n {1}", i + 1, text);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the text contained in the .TXT file:

> YMJNS HWJIN GQJQJ LFHDT
>   KYMJR FYMJR FYNHF QLJSN
>   ZXLJT WLJGT TQJBN QQGJJ
>   CUQTW JINSF KWJJU ZGQNH
>   YFQPN SMNXM TRJHN YDTKQ
>   NSHTQ STSYM JGNHJ SYJSF
>   WDTKM NXGNW YMXYT UGTTQ
>   JBFXG TWSTS YMJXJ HTSIT
>   KSTAJ RGJWJ NLMYJ JSKNK
>   YJJSN SYTRT IJXYK FRNQD
>   HNWHZ RXYFS HJXYM JXTST
>   KFXMT JRFPJ WXYTU QFWLJ
>   QDXJQ KYFZL MYMJB JSYTS
>   YTGJH TRJTS JTKYM JBTWQ
>   I’XKN SJXYR FYMJR FYNHN
>   FSXBM TXJBT WPSTB KTWRX
>   YMJGF XNXTK HTRUZ YJWXH
>   NJSHJ FSIJQ JHYWT SNHHN
>   WHZNY WDXYT UMJQF NIYMJ
>   KTZSI FYNTS XTKYM JINLN
>   YFQJW FFSIN XBNIJ QDWJH
>   TLSNX JIFXY MJKTW JKFYM
>   JWTKY MJINL NYFQF LJXYT
>   UGTTQ JFSFQ LJGWF NXSTB
>   FKZSI FRJSY FQFXU JHYTK
>   RTIJW SRFYM JRFYN HXFSI
>   TAJWY MJQFX YHJSY ZWDBF
>   XZXJI YTKTW RYMJY MJTWJ
>   YNHFQ KTZSI FYNTS TKRTI
>   JWSHT RUZYJ WXHNJ SHJJS
>   I

Comment: I have noticed the bottom is meant to be decoded_text not text but it still hasn't resolved the issue

Comment: set breakpoints and step through your application in order to see what it is doing at every step of the way.

Comment: Why are you adding something to `text` when it's supposed to be input?

Comment: Change `shift <= 0` to `shift < 0`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have changed the bottom two things to decoded _text, didnt realise I made that mistake but it still hasn't resolved my issue.

Comment: Changing things at random until they work is not a good technique. Please read this. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In particular heed the advice to *break up the program into small methods*.  Can you write a method that takes a string and a shift and returns the shifted string?  If you can do that, then that method is *simpler* than the program you have, and you can *use* that method in a loop that tries many different shifts. The simpler method will be easier to write and it will be easier to debug when you get it wrong.

Comment: Another good bit of advice is to go through your program and make sure that everything is named according to what it does on the tin.  Why do you have two variables `c` and `character` that do the same thing? Why do you have variables `text` and `decoded_text` which are easily confused?  `encodedText` and `decodedText` would be less easily confused. And so on. Mistakes like the ones you're making here are often a result of confusion caused by earlier poor choices.

Comment: Another good bit of advice is to ask yourself whether a variable mutation needs to happen. Suppose shift is zero. What happens? You add 26 to it. Then you check to see if it is 26, and if it is, you subtract 26 from it, taking it back to zero.  Is that right? Maybe, but it sure looks *crazy*. Also, where did the magic number 26 come from? Far better would be to make this two variables: one for the index, and one for the shift. Deduce the shift from the index, and assign the shift variable *once*, not *three times*.

Comment: @EricLippert But of course the instructor should be giving this good advice.

Comment: See your classmates SO [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34296638/451475).