# C# Caesar Cipher can't decipher

Tags: c#, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a C# Caesar Cipher for an assignment. I have been trying to do this for quite a while and am making no headway whatsoever.

The problem I am having now is that rather than use my encrypted_text and deciphering it, it just [cycles through that alphabet, ignoring the character that it started on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2ybm.png)What is supposed to happen is it is meant to take the encrypted_text and cycle through the alphabet changing each letter by a certain number.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class cipher
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string encrypted_text = "exxego";
        string decoded_text = "";
        char character;
        int shift = 0;
        bool userright = false;

        char[] alphabet = new char[26] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to shift? (Between 0 and 26)");
            shift = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (shift > 26)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Over the limit");
                userright = false;
            }
            if (shift < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Under the limit");
                userright = false;
            }
            if (shift <= 26 && shift >= 0)
            {
                userright = true;
            }
        } while (userright == false);

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            decoded_text = "";
            foreach (char c in encrypted_text)
            {
                character = c;

                if (character == '\'' || character == ' ')
                    continue;

                shift = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, character) - i;
                if (shift <= 0)
                    shift = shift + 26;

                if (shift >= 26)
                    shift = shift - 26;


                decoded_text += alphabet[shift];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nShift #{0} \n{1}", i + 1, decoded_text);
        }

        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("decryptedtext.txt");
        file.WriteLine(decoded_text);
        file.Close();

    }
}
```

As you can see from my picture, I am getting close. I just need to be able to crack this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please forgive me if this is a simple question/solution, I am really new to this.

Comment: My apologies, but I can't help to interweave a pun: you can't decaesarcipher...

Comment: Just curious what and where this class is, this is not the first instance of it today.Here is the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34294390/451475).

Comment: It's University of Lincoln. That person is doing the exact same assessment as me... small world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alphabet contains upper case characters, but your input is fully in lower case. You need to handle this situation either by casting all input to same case, or handling both upper/lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you! I have been stupidly stuck on this for longer than I care to admit. I will accept your answer in 3 mins, when I can. Thanks again!

Comment: I would also advise you not to do conditions like this: if (shift <= 0)                    shift = shift + 26; because it will produce mistakes that would be hard to catch, better throw or display some message so that you would not spend too much time seeking the issue

Comment: Even more great advice, thank you. You've been a great help!

Comment: There is a great similarity to another question on Stodgy, right down to `if (shift <= 0) shift = shift + 26;`.